# Wrapping a std::string for use in a boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, c++98

I wish to have a boost::variant which contains a range of different types including std::string and my own class called Path. Path is effectively a string itself, at least at the time being, but it is a very different concept in terms of the application itself and when visiting it I will be doing very different this with this string. Now of course I cant simply typedef Path as a std::string, so what is the best way to define my Path class?

**UPDATE**

Here is my solution:

```
struct Path
{
    Path()
    {
    }

    Path(std::string& _value): value(_value)
    {
    }

    Path(const char* _value): value(_value)
    {
    }

    bool operator==(const Path& right) const
    {
        return value==right.value;
    }

    bool operator!=(const Path& right) const
    {
        return value!=right.value;  
    }

    bool operator<(const Path& right) const
    {
        return value<right.value;
    }

    std::string value;
};
```

Comment: I would suggest looking at `union` or making Path and a String type inherit from `std::string`.

Comment: If your `Path` class is to be used as a directory path, there is already a [`path`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#class-path) class in the [Boost filesystem](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm) library.

Comment: @ilent2 No, don't inherit from `std::string`, it is not intended to be inherited (or it would have a virtual destructor).

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Yes that's what I was thinking!

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg No its not the same thing but thanks anyway!

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Incidentally, is there a reason why std::basic_string isn't final in C++11 (at least that's the case for g++-4.8). Backwards compat?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Although not always possible, isn't inheritance still fine as long as you aren't using dynamic memory?

Comment: @thokra It's most likely because of backwards compatibility.

Comment: @ilent2 But using `std::string` *is* using dynamic memory. How else would you add to a string if it didn't dynamically allocate/reallocate when needed?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I meant relative to the virtual/non-virtual destructor of a class.

Comment: @ilent2 Well, you're right in a way, since you can't do anything that demands a destructor in the inherited class.

Comment: What about boost::strong_typedef?